# Picking a random image out of different directories based on GEO locations

Tags: php, cloudflare

The code for picking an random image out of a directory is pretty straight forward.

For example; my current code is this:

```
<?php
$imagesDir = 'img/';
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)]; // See comments
?>
```

I want to use Cloudflare's GEO IP finder, so when the user visits the website it feeds back where the users from.

So let's say I want,

```
  if england use directory > img/en/ 
  if australia use directory > img/au/
  if USA use directory > img/usa/
  if NZ use directory > img/nz/
  if any other country > img/
```

I know the logic to it, but putting it into code is another thing which i've been struggling to do.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of the location directories and their corresponding names then build your image directory based on the geo location (`$location` in my example).

```
$location = 'australia';

$dirs = array('england'   => 'en',
              'australia' => 'au',
              'USA'       => 'usa',
              'NZ'        => 'nz');

$imagesDir = 'img/' . (isset($dirs[$location]) ? $dirs[$location] . '/' : '');
```

If a location is not found in the array the setting of the `$imagesDir` variable will default to `img/` as it is now.

Comment: How would you cope with 'any other country'?

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to add that to your answer.

Comment: It's already there, in the setting of `$imagesDir` any value not found in the array will default ot just the `'img/'`.

Comment: What I mean is that your code needs a bit of explaining, because this might not be obvious to everyone.

Comment: Additionally the 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' header -- see [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), than can be found via `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` may be useful. The fact that a user is serving your website from a specific country, or an ip originating from a particular country, doesn't necessarily mean he'd like to see that image. I, a Dutchman, could be surfing from London, England, for a number of reasons... You may also combine the two and use the _GEO IP finder_ as back-up.

Comment: @Niellles the HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE header might not always be present or be rather difficult to parse, but the idea is good.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware that's why I suggested to still use the GEO IP finder as back-up, the Accept-Language may very well only contain a language and no region -- which might make guessing a little hard. If it does contain a region however, it's probably a better source of information than the IP. Depending of course on whether the current/actual location v.s. the normal/most regular location of the user is relevant in this use case.

Comment: This is a perfect solution and works like a charm - thanks! Can I ask, does anyone know why has my question been down voted? It's not been asked on stackoverflow before, so it's adding value to the forum. If I'm doing anything wrong, I'd like to know!

Comment: Please consider clicking the large checkmark under the answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: Hi Dave, I have but because I'm new my votes don't count publicly. I'm very sorry! In time when I have more rep it'll count though.

Comment: Not the up arrow there should be a checkmark under the down arrow that shows that you accept the answer. Should work regardless of your reputation.

Comment: Oh dear, long day.

Comment: @GerryHodson Some people tend to downvote quite quickly when they see that you didn't even attempt anything to solve your problem. It's basically because you ask us to solve it for you, without you putting any effort into it. Your question was a very simple one, you're still learning, but we often see question like: "I need code to analyse who spoke and what they said. The code should be tolerant of background noise and be able to identify multiple speakers, even when they speak simultaneously. It should work on multiple platforms and take up little resources.". This annoys people.

Comment: @GerryHodson: For instance this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215323/play-audio-file-on-located-on-different-server

Comment: I'm a Mod at the SEO version of Stackoverflow, so I do get the annoyance of people who don't bother to try to after things through their own research. But, I did try this myself - but I failed miserably. I thought it would be a case of adding a couple of `ifs`and `elses` so I didn't want to jumble the code with my own. Sometimes a bit disheartening when you're new to a language and you get attacked. Either way, the advice on this question was fantastic. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you are just trying to convert "england" -> img/en/
Any straight conversion, like this, I like to use a dictionary/map (depending on the language), or [associative arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for PHP.  Uses a ternary, if the key (country) is not in the array, then "img/"

```
$arr = [
   "england" => "img/en/",
   //...
];
$imagesDir = in_array($COUNTRY, $arr) ? $arr[$COUNTRY] : "img/";
```

Comment: How would you cope with 'any other country'?