# Using Cloudflare CF-IPCountry to pick which folder to grab an image from

Tags: c#, asp.net, cloudflare

I'm currently trying to learn C# and it's kind of alien to me so I apologise if I'm asking something basic.

I'm wanting to use Cloudflares GEO IP, which feeds back a country code eg. US, GB, AU.

Based on the country is given, I want to pick a different directory to randomly pick an image from.

So for example, if CF says GB I want it to pick a random image from /img/gb/.
Exactly like [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51212132/picking-a-random-image-out-of-different-directories-based-on-geo-locations/51212277#51212277), just in C#.

I've written this so far, which works in one folder, but I've been stuck on this part.

```
public class getimage : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
    {
        // Set a default for images
        string imgdirectory = "/img";

        // check if a directory has been given as a source for images
        if (context.Request.QueryString["d"] != null)
        {
            imgdirectory = context.Request.QueryString["d"];
        }

        // read in all the images into an array
        string[] imgarray = Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(imgdirectory), "*.jpg");

        // generate a radom number upto the total number of images
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.Next(0, imgarray.Length);

        // read in the file
        byte[] imageBytes =File.ReadAllBytes(imgarray[randomNumber]);

        // output the image 
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
            ms.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of the code do you have a problem with (you don't say which part)?

Comment: The actual code I have works without Cloudflare. It simply picks a random image from a folder. What I need help with it changing which folder it picks that random image from, based off which country Cloudflare says the users from

Comment: Do you already have code that calls their service?

Comment: Nope. There doesn't seem to be any support from Cloudflare with C#, so I'm a bit of a lost sheep here.

Comment: For now, take a look at the [REST api documentation](https://api.cloudflare.com/#getting-started-endpoints) and some community made libraries like [CloudFlare.Net](https://github.com/JSkimming/CloudFlare.NET). As this question stands, it's too broad to answer here.

Comment: if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("CF-IPCountry"))
{
    Response.Write(Request.Headers["CF-IPCountry"]);
}, apparently this works. But... I cannot implement it. Maybe I haven't added enough info to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = "";
    if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("CF-IPCountry"))
    {
        string countrycode = Request.Headers["CF-IPCountry"].ToString();
        if (Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/img/" + countrycode)))
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/img/" + countrycode + "/"), "*.jpg");
            Random _r = new Random();
            int randomimage = _r.Next(files.Length);
            filename = "/img/" + countrycode + "/" + Path.GetFileName(files[randomimage]);
        }

    }
    if (filename.Length == 0)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/img/none/"), "*.jpg");
        Random _r = new Random();
        int randomimage = _r.Next(files.Length);
        filename = "/img/none/" + Path.GetFileName(files[randomimage]);
    }
    Literal1.Text = filename;
}
```